# String types not allowed (at 'buyButtonAppearance' with value 'android_pay_dark')

Tags: android, aapt

I keep getting this error in Gradle console:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"String types not allowed (at \u0027buyButtonAppearance\u0027 with value \u0027android_pay_dark\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"D:\personal\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\9.4.0\res\values\values.xml","position":{"startLine":44,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":5370,"endLine":56,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":6369}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}'

In the Messages section I keep getting this message:

> D:\personal\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\9.4.0\res\values\values.xml Error:(45, 5) String types not allowed (at 'buyButtonAppearance' with value 'android_pay_dark'). Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is the build.grade of the whole project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me to sort this issue out?

Another build.gradle is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("android.keystore")
            storePassword 'sdsgfgh'
            keyAlias "appexample"
            keyPassword 'sdsgfgh'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
repositories {

    maven { url "https://bitbucket.org/adexim/androidsdk/raw/master/" }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Thia is unreadable. Please edit your question and put this text in there.

Comment: There must be more than 1 build.gradle files. Please post other ones too. Also please copy paste them into the question this time.